# Reading Specific Value from Fire base in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Trying to do a SELECT like query to retrieve data but using Firebase and React Native.

I have the following structure in my Firebase DB:

```
{
  "items" : {
    "1234" : {
      "value1" : 420,
      "value2" : 69,
      "ProductID" : 1234
    },
    "5678" : {
      "value1" : 250,
      "value2" : 12,
      "ProductID" : 5678
    },
    "91011" : {
      "value1" : 9001,
      "value2" : 5,
      "ProductID" : 91011
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the following code to try and retrieve a specific product ID

```
firebaseDB.ref("/items/")
    .orderByChild("ProductID")
    .equalTo(data)
    .once("value", snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            const userData = snapshot.val();
            console.log("INFO ::: Exists!", userData);
        }
        else {
            console.log("INFO ::: No match!!!");
        }
```

Now my issue is I can't seem to select the data. I think it is an issue with my query as I pass the the ID 1234 and it does not find this product id.

```
        .equalTo(data) <---- is how I'm passing the product id
```

This is what gets printed in my logs:

```
[11:43:19] [FIREBASE] p:0: Listen called for /items{"ep":"1234","i":"ProductID","sp":"1234"}
[11:43:19] [FIREBASE] p:0: Listen on /itemsfor {"ep":"1234","i":"ProductID","sp":"1234"}
[11:43:19] [FIREBASE] p:0: {"r":2,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/items","q":{"sp":"1234","ep":"1234","i":"ProductID"},"t":1,"h":""}}
[11:43:19] [FIREBASE] p:0: handleServerMessage d {"p":"items","d":{"1234":{"value1":420,"value2":69,"ProductID":1234},"5678":{"value1":250,"value2":12,"ProductID":5678},"91011":{"value1":9001,"value2":5,"ProductID":91011}}}
[11:43:19] [FIREBASE] event: /items:value:null
[11:43:19] [FIREBASE] p:0: Unlisten called for /items {"ep":"1234","i":"ProductID","sp":"1234"}
[11:43:19] [FIREBASE] p:0: Unlisten on /items for {"ep":"1234","i":"ProductID","sp":"1234"}
```

Perhaps I should try modifying the "value" I pass when calling .once but I'm not sure.... Any ideas?

Thanks

Solved Issue:

A solution was given nicely by Mohammed that did allow for the retrieval of the data. What I was overlooking also was that I was using a String to query my data and the data I was looking for was a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```js
const data = 1234;
firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child('items')
  .orderByChild('ProductID')
  .equalTo(data)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapShot => {
    let matchingProducts = [];
    snapShot.forEach(child => {
      matchingProducts = [child.val(), ...matchingProducts];
    });
    console.log("matchingProducts",matchingProducts);
    return matchingProducts;
  });
```

Comment: I think it should be `const data = 1234;` since his Firebase screenshot indicates the `ProductID` is a number.

Comment: Thank you @Mohammed and thank you Alex I got it working eventually with Alex's comment :D